# "Safe" Ab Exercise

Tags: injury-prevention, abdominals, back-pain, lower-back

I've been trying to find safe abdominal exercises.  That is to say, executing the exercises I have learned through my life I can feel the vertebrae in my lower back rubbing/grinding against each other, mostly on the right side.  That usually means pain the morning after.  So I ask, does anyone have any suggestions for "safe" abdominal exercises?

Thanks

Comment: Reverse Crunches, Hanging Leg Raises, Bicycle Crunches.

Comment: um... have you seen a doctor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some people believe that concentric ab work is unnecessary. [*Abs*](http://startingstrength.com/articles/abs_rippetoe.pdf), by Mark Rippetoe outlines the common reasoning and alternatives to concentic ab work. Here's some summary and excerpts.

- The primary role of the abs is *isometric* stabilization.
- "Since the basic nature of correct ab function is isometric, the exercises in which the abs perform this function will provide exercises for the abs as well."
- "As the loads [on a squat or deadlift] pass 200 and then 300+ pounds, it becomes enough of a challenge for the now more experienced lifter that a helluva lot of ab work is required to squat and pull properly."
- Chin-ups, while not supporting the spine also require isometric ab work to hold the body in position. During later reps, there even is a little bit of eccentric/concentric contraction as your abs become tired and relax/tighten every rep.
- "But for most lifters – and I mean the vast majority who will never squat 600, or even 500 – the stresses normally encountered under the bar provide all the work the abs need."
- "For those of you with recurring low back problems, see what six situp-free months does to your back problems."

I find this to be true. When my [deadlift started to get heavy, I noticed my abs got sore](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/11482/why-do-deadlifts-make-my-obliques-sore)! This happens now with my heavier squat sets. Chin-ups and pull-ups always leave my abs sore. I haven't done a sit-up in three months, but my plank has increased from a 1m30s to 3m (and I don't train the plank; I just test it occasionally).

Comment: +1 awesome advice.  Same for me, I don't really do much core exercises, but I squat/deadlift/pull-up so much that people don't believe me when I tell them I don't do sit-ups.  I would just like to add the age old addage applies: "Great Abs start in the Kitchen".

Comment: Thank you Katie.  I'm not strong enough to do chin ups or pullups but I do a lot of [Australian pull ups](http://www.alkavadlo.com/2010/01/07/all-about-australian-pull-ups/).  I'm thinking what I need to do is specifically engage my abs when I do them and hold a [plank](http://www.lilburn-mustangs.org/basketball/planks-exercise.htm) as long as I can as my last exercise.

Comment: Make that Kate.  I can't type

Answer (score 4):

[Planks!](http://www.sparkpeople.com/blog/blog.asp?post=14_plank_exercises_for_a_stronger_core) As long as you have proper form they are very good at building strength for your core without having to do crunches.